# AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'load_dataset'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I'm just trying to run the Seaborn example from here: https://seaborn.pydata.org/installing.html

import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
sns.pairplot(df, hue="species")

but I get the following error: AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'load_dataset'

I have checked and I don't seem to have a file named seaborn.py

Comment: Maybe you have a local file named "seaborn.py"?

Answer (score 0):

I could not replicate it unless you have a package in your environment with the same name 'seaborn'. i would try to install seaborn in a new environment and see if you encounter the error.